# Python Dom Parsing

Tags: python, parsing, dom

I have a xhtml file that has a format like below. I'm trying to pick up all the text between the tags sequentially. I'm able to pick up everything but BAC by calling my `this_list = get_e('td')` then passing that list into another function to get the text as `get_text(this_list)`. I'm wondering if I can make a slight modifications to my functions to get all the text. Can anyone offer some advice on this?

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="lft">
    <a shape="rect" href="http://www.usatoday.idmanagedsolutions.com/stocks/new/quote.idms?SYMBOL_US=BAC">
        BAC</a>
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="lft">
    Bank Of America Corporation</td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    9.79
   </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    -0.07
  </td>
  <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <span class="neg-arrw">
        -0.71%
    </span>
   </td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    71,370,166
   </td>
</tr>
<tr class="evenrow">
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="lft">
    VALE
   </td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" class="lft">
    Vale S A
   </td>
<td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    17.52
   </td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    +0.09
   </td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    <span class="pos-arrw">
        +0.49%
    </span>
   </td>
   <td colspan="1" rowspan="1">
    15,461,788</td>
</tr>
```

I'm using the functions below

```
def get_e(tag):
    l=[]
    els=dom.getElementsByTagName(tag)
    for e in els:
        for child_el in els.childNode:
            lst.append(child_el)
    return l

def get_text(els):
    l=[]
    for e in els
        if e.nodeType == e.TEXT_NODE:
            l.append(e.data)
    return lst
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The get_text function expects input that has just text nodes. Some of your td's have embedded a's which are element nodes. I've updated this to call get_e recursively on seeing element nodes.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import pdb

def get_e(dom, tag):
    l=[]
    els=dom.getElementsByTagName(tag)
    for e in els:
        for child_el in e.childNodes:
            # if this was an element node get its children
            if child_el.nodeType == e.ELEMENT_NODE:
                l.extend(get_e(e, child_el.tagName))
            else:
                l.append(child_el)
    return l

def get_text(els):
    l=[]
    for e in els:
        if e.nodeType == e.TEXT_NODE:
            l.append(e.data)
    return l

dom = minidom.parse('s.xml')
print get_text(get_e(dom, 'td'))
```

Or perhaps you could consider the shorter :-

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
et = ET.parse('s.xml')
print [e.findtext('.') for e in et.findall('.//*')]
```